# primefaces decreasing spacing between panelGrid rows

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use primefaces panelGrid, row and column. The code is below. I wan't to decrease spacing between rows. How can I do?

```
<p:panelGrid>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>row 1 col1</p:column>
        <p:column>row 1 col2</p:column>

    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>row 2 col1</p:column>
        <p:column >row 2 col2</p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>row 3 col1</p:column>
        <p:column >row 3 col2</p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>row 4 col1</p:column>
        <p:column >row 4 col2</p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding this css row height decreases. "The default value is 4px 10px".

```
.ui-panelgrid td {
    padding: 2px 5px ;
}
```

Comment: With latest Primefaces 8, it might be required to change the selector to `body .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell`

Comment: This will affect all the panel grids. How can I do it only one selected grid?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you'll want to use CSS to change the style applied to the generated markup.

Depending on exactly what you want, you may want to assign an id to the panelgrid and select using that in your stylesheet. Apply CSS margin/padding properties as appropriate to the tr element.

View source or use your browser's inspector to narrow down exactly what markup is being generated; this'll make it easier for you to figure out exactly what CSS you'll need to write.